# Paging 3 initial loading not shown

Tags: android, paging, android-paging, android-paging-library

I am working with paging 3, everything work fine except initial loading state. I am adding `withLoadStateFooter` but it never show loading state at first call

Here is my implementation

**Load State Adapter**

```
class LoadStateAdapter (
    private val retry: () -> Unit
): LoadStateAdapter<LoadStateViewHolder>() {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LoadStateViewHolder, loadState: LoadState) {
        holder.bindTo(loadState)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        loadState: LoadState
    ): LoadStateViewHolder {
        return LoadStateViewHolder.create(parent, retry)
    }
}
```

**Load State View Holder**

```
class LoadStateViewHolder(
    view : View,
    private val retryCallback: () -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    private val progressBar = view.findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progress_bar)
    private val errorMsg = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.error_msg)
    private val btnRetry = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.retry_button)
        .also {
            it.setOnClickListener { retryCallback() }
        }
    private var loadState : LoadState? = null

    companion object {
        fun create(parent: ViewGroup, retryCallback: () -> Unit): LoadStateViewHolder {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.network_state_item, parent, false)
            return LoadStateViewHolder(
                view,
                retryCallback
            )
        }
    }


    fun bindTo(loadState: LoadState) {
        this.loadState = loadState

        btnRetry.isVisible = loadState !is LoadState.Loading
        errorMsg.isVisible = loadState !is LoadState.Loading
        progressBar.isVisible = loadState is LoadState.Loading

        if (loadState is LoadState.Error){
            errorMsg.text = loadState.error.localizedMessage
        }
    }
}
```

**Paging Source**

```
override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Model> {

    try {
        // Load page 1 if undefined.
        val currentPage = params.key ?: 0
        val offset = currentPage * 50

        val requestParams = hashMapOf<String, Any>()
        requestParams.put("limit", 50)
        requestParams.put("offset", offset)

        val response =  repository.getList(requestParams)
        val isFinish = response.paging != null && response.paging!!.next == null

        return LoadResult.Page(
            data = response.data ?: mutableListOf(),
            prevKey = null, // Only paging forward.
            nextKey = if (isFinish) null else currentPage + 1
        )
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // Handle errors in this block
        return LoadResult.Error(e)
    }
}
```

**View Model**

```
val listPagingFlow = Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 50)) {
    MyPagingSource(repository)
}.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

**Activity**

```
    val pagingAdapter = MyPagingAdapter()
    list.apply {
        setHasFixedSize(true)
        adapter = pagingAdapter.withLoadStateFooter(
            footer = LoadStateAdapter { pagingAdapter.retry() }
        )
    }

    lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        viewModel.listPagingFlow.collectLatest { pagingData ->
            pagingAdapter.submitData(pagingData)
        }
    }
```

*MyPagingAdapter* is simple `PagingDataAdapter`

**In short; loading state works fine but it did not showing at first request. Can any one help?**

Current version `3.0.0-alpha04`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`withLoadStateFooter` returns a `ConcatAdapter` which concatenates results from original `PagingDataAdapter` with a `LoadStateAdapter` that listens to `CombinedLoadState.append` events. So it's not expected for it to return an item during initial load (loadType == `REFRESH`), and it was designed this way because it doesn't really make sense to show a "footer" before any items has loaded.

However, to achieve what you want you can simply create your own ConcatAdapter which mirrors the implementation of `.withLoadStateFooter` very closely:

```
val originalAdapter = MyPagingDataAdapter(...)
val footerLoadStateAdapter = MyFooterLoadStateAdapter(...)

addLoadStateListener { loadStates ->
    // You need to implement some logic here to update LoadStateAdapter.loadState
    // based on however you want to prioritize between REFRESH / APPEND load states.
    // Something really basic might be:
    // footerLoadStateAdapter.loadState = when {
    //     loadStates.refresh is NotLoading -> loadStates.append
    //     else -> loadStates.refresh
    // }
    footerLoadStateAdapter.loadState = ...
}
return ConcatAdapter(originalAdapter, footerLoadStateAdapter)
```

Comment: I didn't understand the answer. Can you give me some references or links?

Comment: Neither did I, I'm having a similar problem but cant understand a propper solution, any help?

Comment: How can I clarify the sample code above? A `ConcatAdapter` combines the data from multiple adapters into one, which let's you display data from multiple adapters in a `RecyclerView`. `LoadStateAdapter` is a built-in from the Paging library which displays 0 or 1 items depending on what `displayLoadStateAsItem` returns, and you can set the state via the public mutable property. See https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/LoadStateAdapter#displayLoadStateAsItem(androidx.paging.LoadState)

Comment: This sample is showing an example of how to customize the default behavior of LoadStateAdapter, so you can choose when it switches to another LoadState. Some people may be interested in a combination of LoadStates from different LoadTypes depending on their use-case.

Answer (score 8):

Using the footer `LoadStateAdapter` for showing initial loading will cause issues. The list will automatically be scrolled to the bottom as mentioned in the comments.

The way to go about this is to use two `LoadStateAdapter`s, one to show the initial loading and the second to show loading when more items are being loaded.

```
fun <T : Any, V : RecyclerView.ViewHolder> PagingDataAdapter<T, V>.withLoadStateAdapters(
    header: LoadStateAdapter<*>,
    footer: LoadStateAdapter<*>
): ConcatAdapter {
    addLoadStateListener { loadStates ->
        header.loadState = loadStates.refresh
        footer.loadState = loadStates.append
    }

    return ConcatAdapter(header, this, footer)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest lifting the initial loading and empty state out of the paging adapter and do it like this:

```
adapter.loadStateFlow.collect {
    // to determine if we are done with the loading state, 
    // you should have already  shown your loading view elsewhere when the entering your fragment
    if (it.prepend is LoadState.NotLoading && it.prepend.endOfPaginationReached) {
        loading.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    if (it.append is LoadState.NotLoading && it.append.endOfPaginationReached) {
        emptyState.isVisible = adapter.itemCount < 1
    }
}
```

The logic is

- If the append has finished (*it.append is LoadState.NotLoading && it.append.endOfPaginationReached == true*), and our adapter items count is zero (*adapter.itemCount < 1*), means there is nothing to show, so we show the empty state
- If the prepend has finished (*it.prepend is LoadState.NotLoading && it.prepend .endOfPaginationReached == true*), then we are already done with the initial loading view and we should hide it

Answer (score 1):

As [@dlam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63459132/11085663) answer you can use custom ConcatAdapter in your adapter instead of withLoadStateFooter

```
fun withMySpecificFooter(
    footer: LoadStateAdapter<*>
): ConcatAdapter {
    addLoadStateListener { loadStates ->
        footer.loadState = when (loadStates.refresh) {
            is LoadState.NotLoading -> loadStates.append
            else -> loadStates.refresh
        }
    }
    return ConcatAdapter(this, footer)
}
```

Comment: it's working but why list items showing from middle?
i.e if i have 10 item, recyclerview showing 5th item in initial and must scroll to top for seeing first item.

Comment: @HadiAhmadi same problem

Comment: I encountered the same problem with RecyclerView starting at the middle whenever withLoadStateFooter() is used.  Does anyone know how to fix this issue?  Thanks in advance.